# How to add a Hamburger Menu in Joomla 3

Tags: jquery, css, joomla, hamburger-menu

I am looking to find out how I could add a hamburger menu to a Joomla Site that I am building. I have come across the following tutorial but unfortunately, the section where I am asked to add HTML code is broken so I was looking for some advice.

https://www.joomlalondon.co.uk/jugl-blog/how-to/how-to-create-a-mobile-hamburger-menu-for-joomla-default-template-protostar

I would appreciate it if somebody could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find an extension to do this for you in the Joomla Extensions Directory e.g. [Mobile Menu CK](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mobile-menu-ck) (free), [Responsive Menu](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/responsive-menu) (paid), [Mobile menu](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mobile-menu) (paid) or similar.

I like [RokNavMenu](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/roknavmenu) (free) which includes a hamburger menu for the mobile version of the website but you might need to hide the desktop version of the menu if it's not needed using custom CSS or similar.

Comment: Thanks Neil for your response, will have a look at the links you posted

Comment: Hi Neil, The ones that you have mentioned are not free. Is there any alternative you can help us with? where in we can write our own custom code to achieve the same result?

Comment: I have updated my answer as one of the extensions I recommended previously as a free extension now seems to be a paid extension.